# java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'library_idlibrary' cannot be null

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, orm

I'm making one to many relationship in hibernate, but when i try to insert a value 
in the tables I get exception that my FK in photos entity can't be null.

My parent entity:

```
@Table(name = "library")
@Entity
public class Book {
@OneToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        mappedBy = "book",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
)
// setters / getters and other columns
```

My  child entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "photos")
public class photos{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "idphotos")
private int id;


@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "library_idlibrary")
private Book book;
// other columns
```

Exception:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'library_idlibrary' cannot be null
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:115)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:960)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1116)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1066)
```

I have DAO object and controller which are inserting values :

Controller:

```
  @PostMapping( value = "/newBook",consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public String add(@ModelAttribute("book") @Valid Book book, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam(value = "photo", required = false) List<MultipartFile> photos, @RequestParam(value = "valute",required = false) String valute,BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "addBook";}

    List<entity.photos> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (MultipartFile photo : photos) {
        File file =null;
        if (!photo.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                validateImg(photo);
                file = new File(context.getRealPath("/uploadFile/" + photo.getOriginalFilename()));
                Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("THE PATH IS " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(photo.getInputStream(), file);
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                result.reject("uk_UA", "Поганий тип");
                return "addBook";
            }
        }
        if (file != null) {
            photos ph = new photos(photo.getOriginalFilename());
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(file.getAbsolutePath());
            Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("SOMETHING HAS BROKEN IN LOGGING FILE");
            System.out.println("INSIDE ADD METHOD ");
            list.add(ph);

        } else list.add(new photos(""));
    }
    book.getPhotosList().addAll(list);
    service.add(book);

    return "redirect:/books";
}
```

DAO:

```
   public void add(Book user) {
        currentSession().save(user);
}
```

Comment: put the code that is invoking the hibernate save method.

Comment: Ok,  I have updated the question!

Comment: my answer is correct I am not seeing where you set the backreference of the photo to the book. You are only adding the photo to the list without setting the back referece.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you have not set your backreference from the Photo to the Book and then you cascade the persist/merge operation from the Book through the photoes collection. When you add element to collection you need to maintain both sides of the relationship. For example:

```
Book book = new Book();
Photo photo = new Photo();
book.addPhoto(photo);
photo.setBook(book);
//notice on the line above we set the backreference of the photo to the book.
hibernateSession.persist(book);
// now it is cascading from book to photo and it will set the foreign keys correctly.
```

Comment: Is there any way to do that automatically with annotation as example